# How to convert html string into plain text in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

How do I convert html string (with a lot of tags etc.) into plain text in React? Any npm module maybe?

I haven't found any methods for converting **html string to plain text**. I need this because I want to save a text file edited in [Ckeditor 5](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/index.html) as a plain text file, but Ckeditor 5 manages data in html or markdown format.

Comment: You want to Render HTML string as real HTML in a React component ?

Comment: No, I want to get plain text string (free from any html tags) from an html string.

Comment: You can create an in-memory element and use `.innerText` on it. `const div = document.createElement('div'); div.innerHTML = htmlString; return div.innerText;`

Comment: James Whiteley, no. It converts jsx to string, but it does not deletes all those <p>, <div> etc. tags. And it only works for actual React components, and I need it to work for any html string.

Comment: It would be better to not let the user insert any markup information (like in markdown) in the first place so you don't have to strip that out and can safely assume that all the text is actually only text. It's also not possible to safely determine if a plain text does intentionally contain text that looks like markup or not.

Comment: What if I wanted to have a plain text containing the plain string `<p>This is how you make a paragraph in HTML</p>`. How do you know you shouldn't strip those markup out of my document? It is entirely context based.

Comment: So in other words: If your goal is to let the user enter plain text and save that as plain text you should use an editor that doesn't insert any markup or can be configured to not insert any markup. If it doesn't insert any markup you will not have to strip it out afterwards (which is anyways not safely possible as I already mentioned).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can write your own piece of code to make that happen, no library needed.

```
var htmlString = "<h1><b>test</b></h1>";
var plainString = htmlString.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');

console.log(plainString ); // you will have your plain text
```

or

```
function getText(html){
    var divContainer= document.createElement("div");
    divContainer.innerHTML = html;
    return divContainer.textContent || divContainer.innerText || "";
}

var yourString= "<div><h1>Hello World</h1>\n<p>We are in SOF</p></div>";

console.log(getText(yourString));
```

Comment: AFAIK `he.decode` isn't vanilla JS, is it from a library?

Comment: FYI, usinf reex over htmlstring is a bad bad bad idea

Comment: you are correct! @Rajesh added one more solution without a regex.

Comment: For htmlString.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, ''); &nbsp; is not being replaced. What to do if followed this method?