# ./node_modules/@selderee/plugin-htmlparser2/lib/hp2-builder.mjs Attempted import error: 'Picker' is not exported from 'selderee'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, npm, npm-package

When I am going to import htmlToText package I am getting this error

```
import { htmlToText } from 'html-to-text';
```

then I got this error

```
./node_modules/@selderee/plugin-htmlparser2/lib/hp2-builder.mjs
Attempted import error: 'Picker' is not exported from 'selderee'.
```

Comment: Did you tried with `require` instead of `import`  ?

Comment: But I am using this package in react, how could I use require instead of import,

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue. If you have a full stack React app, here's what worked for me.
Send the html from the front end to the backend in the body of an Axios request. Call html-to-text at your API endpoint, then send the response back to the frontend where you'll be using it

Comment: if there is no backend is there any fix?

Comment: There might be, but I couldn't find one :( maybe try a different package?

Comment: @LakinduHewawasam Or you can use RegEx like in this answer:\

`var htmlString = "<h1><b>test</b></h1>"\
var plainString = htmlString.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');\
console.log(plainString ); // you will have your plain text`\

[link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63574937/how-to-convert-html-string-into-plain-text-in-react)

Comment: oh okay, i will give this a try !

Comment: Thanks @sarahm16...Your regEx solution worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my html-to-text version is 7.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Te solution is to install :

> html-to-text ^7.1.1

make a downgrade to 7.1.1 version