# Cannot make a new line using <br /> html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem breaking down 1 line using `<br />`, I have converted to string but it doesn't work. I have followed this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63574937/how-to-convert-html-string-into-plain-text-in-react` answer to follow edit, it still doesn't work.

This intl.formatMessage({ id: "AUTH.LOGIN.DESCRIPTION.1" }) is `System may takes some time to generate the email. Kindly login when you had received the email. <br /> Thank you for your understanding and apologise for the inconvenience caused.`

```html
const htmlFormatMessage = intl.formatMessage({ id: "AUTH.LOGIN.DESCRIPTION.1" });
const htmlString = htmlFormatMessage;
const plainString = htmlString.replace(/<br\/>/gi, '\n');

<p className="text-muted font-weight-bold">
   {plainString}
</p>
```

Now my result is shown below:

[image: img1]

I want the actual result to be shown below:

[image: img2]

Comment: Typo: Your regular expression is missing the space between the `br` and the `/` that exists in the HTML.

Comment: You can use [Dangerously Set innerHTML](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html). Important that you are sure your string comes from a trusted source

Comment: @Quentin Can you write down which I get missing?

Comment: You are missing a space.

Comment: @FattSky a space. The code has `<br />` you're matching only `<br/>`

Comment: @Quentin Like this right? const plainString = htmlString.replace(/<br\ />/gi, '\n');

Comment: Now you're escaping the space, but not escaping the `/` so that won't even compile.

Comment: Can you show me how? Sorry, I am not really clear

Comment: `htmlString.replace(/<br[^\>]+>/gi, '\n')` should do the trick, it matches any content inside your `<br/>`, it could have a class or spaces

Comment: @savageGoat Thanks for your commet. I tried your code, but why cannot jump in the next line?

Comment: It doesn't break the line because break line in text `\n` don't apply unless the CSS tells to apply them, you could use `white-space: pre-line` or parse your text and splitting it to replace your `&lt;br /&gt;` text (which is why you have `<br />` in your text) into a proper `<br/>` DOM element. React does that do avoid HTML injections

Comment: Alternatively, if you are 100% sure your code is safe, you could use React's property `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337289/react-js-set-innerhtml-vs-dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: @savageGoat I use this `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to make it like this `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: [{htmlFormatMessage}]}}></div>` still cannot work

Comment: My bad, then I guess you could make it double `htmlString.replace(/<br[^\>]+>/gi, '\n\n')` to display not only a break line but an empty line following your break (having your CSS with `white-space: pre-line;`)

Comment: @savageGoat I use your method to edit like this `const plainString = htmlString.replace(/<br[^\>]+>/gi, '\n\n');` still cannot jump to next line

Comment: Are you sure your element has the CSS property `white-space: pre-line`? Otherwise you could have a thousand line breaks, HTML will still hide them